# how to forward null values in my dataframe based on condition from another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to forward-fill null values based on 2 conditions in the below dataframe 'test'.

```
Name    Date     A      B         C        D     Status   Gap
abv 7/7/2018    61     1.83       87       33      Y       0
abv 7/8/2018    NULL    NULL     NULL     NULL    NULL     1
abv 7/9/2018    NULL    NULL     NULL     NULL    NULL     1
abv 7/10/2018   NULL    NULL     NULL     NULL    NULL     1
abv 7/11/2018   NULL    4.19     NULL     NULL    NULL     0
dfg 8/12/2018   42      4.16    151        82      Y       0
dfg 8/13/2018   56      NULL    NULL       45     NULL     0
dfg 8/14/2018   NULL    NULL    NULL      NULL    NULL     1
dfg 8/15/2018   NULL    NULL    NULL      NULL    NULL     1
dfg 8/16/2018   NULL    NULL    NULL      NULL    NULL     1
dfg 8/17/2018   NULL    NULL    NULL      NULL    NULL     1
dfg 8/18/2018   NULL    NULL    NULL      NULL    NULL     1
dfg 8/19/2018   38      2.98    15          85     Y       0
dfg 8/20/2018   NULL    NULL    NULL      NULL    NULL     1
dfg 8/21/2018   NULL    NULL    NULL      NULL    NULL     1
kjl 10/23/2018  NULL    0       72        NULL     N       0
kjl 10/24/2018  NULL    NULL    NULL      NULL    NULL     1
kjl 10/28/2018  NULL    NULL    NULL      NULL    NULL     1
kjl 10/29/2018  54      4.74    212        75      N       0
```

case1

for forward fill

for all records of same Name column, forward fill with limit of 2 records should be applied
if gap = 0 and status = y for current record and gap = 1 for subsequent records.

Case2:
 case gap =0 and status = y for current record and gap = 0 for subsequent records, forward fill should not be applied for null values.

Below is my code logic.

```
if [(test['Status'] == 'Y') & (test['Gap'] == 0) & (test['Gap'].shift(1) == 1)]:
    test1 = test.fillna(method = 'ffill', limit =2)
```

Here, my code is not checking the third condition(where the subsequent record has gap = 0) and keeps forward filling, thus violating case2 condition.

Here is the expected output :

```
Name    Date     A      B         C        D     Status   Gap
abv 7/7/2018    61     1.83       87       33      Y       0
abv 7/8/2018    61     1.83       87       33      Y       1
abv 7/9/2018    61     1.83       87       33      Y       1
abv 7/10/2018   NULL   NULL      NULL     NULL    NULL     1
abv 7/11/2018   NULL    4.19     NULL     NULL    NULL     0
dfg 8/12/2018   42      4.16    151        82      Y       0
dfg 8/13/2018   56      NULL    NULL       45     NULL     0
dfg 8/14/2018   NULL    NULL    NULL      NULL    NULL     1
dfg 8/15/2018   NULL    NULL    NULL      NULL    NULL     1
dfg 8/16/2018   NULL    NULL    NULL      NULL    NULL     1
dfg 8/17/2018   NULL    NULL    NULL      NULL    NULL     1
dfg 8/18/2018   NULL    NULL    NULL      NULL    NULL     1
dfg 8/19/2018   38      2.98    15          85     Y       0
dfg 8/20/2018   38      2.98    15          85     Y       1
dfg 8/21/2018   38      2.98    15          85     Y       1
kjl 10/23/2018  NULL    0       72        NULL     N       0
kjl 10/24/2018  NULL    NULL    NULL      NULL    NULL     1
kjl 10/25/2018  NULL    NULL    NULL      NULL    NULL     1
kjl 10/26/2018  NULL    NULL    NULL      NULL    NULL     1
kjl 10/27/2018  NULL    NULL    NULL      NULL    NULL     1
kjl 10/28/2018  NULL    NULL    NULL      NULL    NULL     1
kjl 10/29/2018  54      4.74    212        75      N       0
```

Comment: how it relates to SQL-Server? BTW the code works, you just expect different results.

Comment: any leads for this question?

Comment: You've made the right move of excluding SQL-Server tag, which might help.